# Got less output with print0 option on find?

Tags: find

I have read the man page and other references, but I am still confused by the behavior of find with `-print0` option.

```
-print0      This primary always evaluates to true.  It prints the pathname of
             the current file to standard output, followed by an ASCII NUL
             character (character code 0).
```

First command:

```
$ find /some/path/ -iname "*intro*jpeg" -o -iname "*intro*jpg" 2> /dev/null
/some/path//asdf199Intro-5kqlw.jpeg
/some/path/199intro-2jjaj.JPEG
/some/path/199intro-3.jpg
/some/path/wuer199intro-4.JPG
/some/path/xbzf199INTRO-1.jpg
```

Second command:

```
$ find /some/path/ -iname "*intro*jpeg" -o -iname "*intro*jpg" 2> /dev/null -print0
/some/path/136intro-3.jpg/some/path/wuer136intro-4.JPG/some/path/xbzf136INTRO-1.jpg
```

I can see that the the filenames from the second command are null character separated, but why do I get 3 output as opposed to 5 above?

Comment: Technically, they're null _terminated_, not null separated.  (There's a NUL after every pathname, including the last one.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your first example

```
 find /some/path/ -iname "*intro*jpeg" -o -iname "*intro*jpg"
```

is not equivalent to

```
 find /some/path/ -iname "*intro*jpeg" -o -iname "*intro*jpg" -print
```

It is equivalent to

```
 find /some/path/ \( -iname "*intro*jpeg" -o -iname "*intro*jpg" \) -print
```

When your expression contains any action other than `-purge`, the implicit print is no longer added.  You want

```
find /some/path/ \( -iname "*intro*jpeg" -o -iname "*intro*jpg" \) -print0 2> /dev/null
```

The reason that you're only getting 3 filenames is that those are the ones matched by your second condition (the one that has an action).  What you typed really means

```
find /some/path/ \( -iname "*intro*jpeg" \) -o \( -iname "*intro*jpg" -print0 \)
```

Which hopefully makes it clear why only 1 side prints anything.

Comment: FYI you can simplify the find expression with: `find /some/path -iregex '.*intro.*\.jpe?g'`...and since there is now only one expression it will avoid the issue highlighted by cjm.

Comment: @cjm the parentheses saved my day, I fixed a 0-day bug in my script!!!

Comment: @mltsy it's not confusing, its regular expression ;-).